# How to install Leaflet.draw plugin?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I'm having trouble with installing [Leaflet.draw plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw). I've spent several hours trying to figure out how to install it, but failed.  Can someone please explain to me how can I use it?

Comment: You can link the leaflet.draw script from CDN - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/leaflet.draw

Comment: Thanks so much for asking this question. Crazy that the readme doesn't start with this.

Comment: cnd option: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7730264

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use the Leaflet.draw plugin, you need to add the js and css files to your html header, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Leaflet stylesheets/javascript -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
    <script src="leaflet.js"></script>


    <!-- Leaflet.draw main plug in files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/leaflet.draw.css" /> <!--add here-->
    <script src="files/Leaflet.draw.js"></script>           <!--and here-->
</head>
<body>
[...]
```

I keep my Leaflet.draw organized inside a `files` directory.

This [official example Leaflet.draw webpage](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/master/docs/examples/basic.html) might come in handy.  Note that they add each plug-in piece individually, but you only need to add the main source code files `Leaflet.draw.js` and `leaflet.draw.css`.

Answer (score 7):

To install using **npm**:

```
npm install leaflet-draw
```

For saving in **package.json**:

```
npm install leaflet-draw --save
```

For **global** installation:

```
npm install -g leaflet-draw
```

Comment: This do not work in VS 2017. Nothing added to the project after npm install command. Only -g options will cause succesfull installation in npm-packages global storage folder